# Pushing Github repo to other existing account (instead of the default account)?

Tags: linux, git, github, push

I am currently learning the basics of Github.  I first created an account through the website with XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX email and XXXXXXXXX username.  Then I started playing around with git commands on my linux machine:

1. Opened the directory I want repo'd to github and initialized with 'git init'
2. For this instance I 'git add' only one directory within my current, which seemed to "track" that collection of files just fine.
3. Then I committed 'git commit' which also worked fine.

The problem for me is that git of course defaulted to credentials based on my linux account.

I then tried to do:
git config --global user.name XXXXXXXXXX(existing git account username)
git config --global user.email XXXXXX@XXXXXX(existing git account email)

The above was successful in changing my account creds, was that the correct way to connect my new local repo to my existing account?

Also, I tried to do another 'git add' for the same sub-directory, which gives no warnings... but on git commit this time, all the files show as untracked.  How do I re-push what I have already committed (to the wrong account), to the newly connected correct account?

Sorry if my git syntax is off, still catching on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse your commit identity with your GitHub account. Those have nothing to do with each other actually. If you create a commit, the author and commiter information is taken as per `user.name` and `user.email`. If you change these after the commit, they are only effective on future commits. If you want to edit for the existing commit, you have to rewrite the commit, or as you just made one commit anyway, you can just delete `.git` and start over.

Actually you can commit with any identity you like, this has absolutely nothing to do with your GitHub account. Well, indirectly it has, but only to link to your account when showing the commits it the used e-mail address is added to your GitHub account.

But the identity used to commit has no influence on whether you are able to push your changes to GitHub or not. Only on push you have to make sure to use the correct credentials of the GitHub account to be able to push the commits.

Comment: That was my confusion, I thought it was "committing" the files to the account master repo. Thank you!!   So essentially all 'commit' is for is saving and tracking changes?

Comment: A commit is a purely local operation. Git is a DVCS (D as in distributed). Each clone (if not explicitly done otherwise) is a full repo with which you can work. You do not need any remote repo if you don't want to share or offsite-backup your repository.